# Appending item to JsonResult data

Tags: c#, json, jsonresult

I have a JsonResult like below:

```
new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = new
                {
                    item01 = "this is the first item",
                    item02 = "this is the second item",
                    item03 = "this is the third item"
                }
            };
```

so what I want is to add other items (suppose item04 and item05) into Data so the new wanted JsonResult would be:

```
new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = new
                {
                    item01 = "this is the first item",
                    item02 = "this is the second item",
                    item03 = "this is the third item",
                    item04 = "this is the fourth item",
                    item05 = "this is the fifth item"
                }
            };
```

How to add item04 and item05 into JsonResult Data to get the result jsut above indicated?

Or better, how can I group item01, item02, item03 into a group and item04 and item05 into another to obtain below data structure?

```
JsonResult r = new JsonResult() { 
                    Data = new { 
                                  group1 = new {
                                              item01 = "this is the first item",
                                              item02 = "this is the second item",
                                              item03 = "this is the third item"
                                  },
                                  group2 = new {
                                              item04 = "this is the fourth item",
                                              item05 = "this is the fifth item"
                                  }
                               }
                   };
```

Comment: So, where is the question?

Comment: I think you can't.. imagine that you have a class with 3 attributes... you can't add more atrributes in another place... except if you create  an `Extension Method`

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes In my case why I cannot built another jsonresult with the new two items? I think it should be possible. I mean, extract data from the first structure and build another one taking into account the 2 new items.

Comment: @user1624552 Imagine again our class with 3 attributes.. now imagine that you have another class with 2 attributes.. you cannot merge them.... what I can suggest is an array... or instead build `Data = new {...}` maybe you can do `Data = new List<Something> {..}` and after that... you access that with `r.Data.Add` I don´t know if will works, but.. you can try..